# Packing a binary into AWS Lambda for Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, lambda, ffmpeg

I want to convert m4a files uploaded to S3 to mp3. The files would only be 15 seconds max, so using Elastic Transcoder would be overkill. I downloaded a binary from https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/. But I am very new to AWS and im still not sure how uploading binaries works. How would I would include it so that I could convert a file?

```
import boto3
import urllib

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'].encode('utf8'))
    try:
    #convert to mp3
    #upload to bucket
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

Comment: Did you try a command line tool like [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-howto)

Comment: Did you find any way to process with this issue? I have the exact same right now..

Comment: Yes, Once I downloaded the binary, I just had to zip it with the source code with both files in root. And run these commands at the beginning of the script. os.system("cp ffmpeg /tmp")
os.system("chmod 775 /tmp/ffmpeg")